# authenticating via facebook to update another database

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

I am very new to web technologies. I don't even know what keywords to search with, so please bear with me.

I want to make a hybrid web app. The user visits the site and gets a login prompt to verify his/her identity via facebook.

When the use logs in correctly, they are allowed to query the database on my website. If the login fails, they cannot query my database.

I do not want any heavy duty SDKs or special purpose libraries. Is there a shortcut, lightweight implementation?

thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have tagged it as javascript, so i would suggest you t go through this official Facebook tutorial : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.2

Once the user is done with this, you just need to allow the user to query your database.

P.S. - For a more appropriate answer in regards to the later section, you need to put forward a more "to the point" question.

Comment: Thank you. I am currently unsure what I'm looking for but your answer seems to send me in the right direction. Unfortunately I don't have 15 points so cannot upvoteyou. I will return and add my vote. Thanks for your help.